# How to generate SQL file from ASP.NET Web app during publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, deployment, entity-framework-migrations

I have a **ASP.NET Web application**, which serves as a backend web api for my Android application.

Now just for development purpose, I am using SmarterAsp.net's free trial hosting. And I have successfully published the web app to the server using Visual Studio 2015 (CE) built in publish tool.

However I now need to setup the **MS SQL database** on the server as well, which requires **SQL files** to run from.

How would I generate the **SQL files** that are needed for my project? I am using **Entity Framework** and used **Code First Migration** that automatically setup my local SQL Server.

It would be preferable if there is a way to do this in VS without having to open up SQL Server and export the sql files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with code first migrations. If you already have migrations enabled, just go to the package manager console and create an [idempotent script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent):

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

This will create a script of all your database objects. If you don't have migrations enabled, then it is fairly easy to configure from the console:

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitialSnapshot -IgnoreChanges
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#enabling